# What unit testing is best for an application which is running on Angular 1.5 among Karma, Protractor or Jasmine or others?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a AngularJS 1.5 application with 5-6 modules with lots relying on directives and stuff.

How do i figure out which testing is better for our application to actually built a test harness over it?

I have been through many types, some are runners and e2e etc.,

Karma, Protractor, Jasmine are the most familiar ones but how would we test the application;

is it whole application one at a time like other automation tools?

OR

is it functionality based?

OR

is it file based?

I know i am pretty much naive to ask this but feeling hard to find the differences and whats best for the application to cover the test harness.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as we know, 
According to angular documentation, they are recommending Karma and jasmine.

### Karma

Karma is a JavaScript command line tool that can be used to spawn a web server which loads your application's source code and executes your tests. You can configure Karma to run against a number of browsers, which is useful for being confident that your application works on all browsers you need to support. Karma is executed on the command line and will display the results of your tests on the command line once they have run in the browser.

Karma is a NodeJS application, and should be installed through npm/yarn. Full installation instructions are available on the Karma website.

### Jasmine

Jasmine is a behavior driven development framework for JavaScript that has become the most popular choice for testing AngularJS applications. Jasmine provides functions to help with structuring your tests and also making assertions. As your tests grow, keeping them well structured and documented is vital, and Jasmine helps achieve this

As per documentation

**And you have to go with module testing instead of file testing**

**It will be controller or functionality based**